# How do "consecutive" logins work?

Tags: support, consecutive-days

I have been noticing that the `consecutive` login marker in the user profile is not working right.

This marker can be found in the `visits` status section on the `visited` line.

I logged in everyday since I registered and it still states that I am never consecutively logging in. I have checked and rechecked if its something I am not doing right, but I have even counted when I login and it should report a lot more consecutive days then it does.

Can anyone please check on this subject and see if I am doing something wrong? It's pointless to have a marker if it doesn't work right.

Comment: Be aware that its not local time but UTC time (very similar to GMT time)

Comment: @RichardTingle AAAh, that right, it should be stated somewhere, because the marker is not accurate if it counts on only one time set. Thanks, that should be the problem!

Comment: *Just* logging in is not enough, you need to be 'active'. What 'active' means is explicitly not public.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What do you mean by "not public"? To participate?

Comment: @GEspinha: As in: the details of what is counted as an active visit are kept secret by Stack Exchange on purpose. We do not know what exactly is counted as a visit for the consecutive days counter.

Comment: ok, I understand. Thanks btw ;)

Comment: Provided you visit several pages (i.e. a question as well as the homepage) and vote / comment / leave an answer etc, then that's pretty active so would count as an active visit.

Comment: I just visit my profile page and make sure the consecutive days counter increments by one. Then I know it counts my visit.  I usually have to refresh my profile page once for it to count it.