# Gobbledygook consecutive days

Tags: support, consecutive-days

*This is not answered in the previous related questions I've seen/read - AFAICT.*

I always login at Stack Overflow. Since I joined up, I've had the habit of typing "Stack" into Google and clicking the top result (or second, depending on how many links *the magazine* has been throwing around).

I then login through SO, and navigate from there to MSO, MSE, etc.

Yesterday/day before, I had about 56 consecutive on SO, and lower on other sites, however currently I have:
SO - 3 consecutive
MSO - 13 consecutive
MSE - 13 consecutive

Not sure where the consecutive have gone from SO, but also, as I always login in at SO first, how could that be lower than the others?

Comment: The strange thing would be that it dropped to something larger than `1` or at most `2` since that doesn't make sense. Other than that, remember that single clicking on a link doesn't necessarily count as activity.

Comment: You know that most browsers feature things such as bookmarks, speed dial, address bar histories, etc., which give you a much easier access to Stack Overflow or whatever your favorite site is?

Comment: @tohecz "*single clicking on a link doesn't necessarily count as activity*" Hmm, I was not aware of that.

Comment: @James AFAIK, the true algorithm is not publicly known to avoid cheating, but this particular thing should be mentioned in one of the threads that appear in the related Qs on the right.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Click browser's "home" button, type "stack", click 1st (or 2nd) link = 3 seconds. Click bookmarks, sigh at the behemothian list that pops up, remembers/finds logical place for Stack, clicks link = 8+ seconds. Yes my bookmarks are organised into *very* logical folders, but I have a lot of them. (Although I did get your sarcasm..)

Comment: @tohecz I'm not sure how one could "cheat" this one by knowing algorithms. To avoid cheating isn't exactly hard - just login, click on a question, and vote/comment/whatever.

Comment: Your question is already answered (with answer acceppted) ....but I would suggest that including links to the "*previous related questions I've seen/read*" would greatly improve the quality of the question. This would help people answering the question to better judge for themselves whether it's been dealt with already or not, and would also help future users looking into how consecutive days work.

Comment: @James. Open browser, type `st` in the address bar, see that it has autosuggested `stackoverflow.com`, press enter. Why travel via Google when you can come directly?

Comment: @Shokhet Fair points, although if users want more info and this question doesn't answer theirs, there is the "Related" on the right and search function. I don't really want to *pollute* my question by linking to other questions with different reasons for the problem - even if arguably for the same issue. That's why we have separate Q&A's. I also think Kate's answer is the important bit now, as other users may find *their* answer from it too.

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen Thanks, but I have a strict habit of going directly to where I need to as a fresh and logical path each time, rather than traipsing through old history (etc) with dupe potentials. One always ends up having to search/find/select from a list and so ends up being slower.

Comment: @James Thing is, I don't think it will "pollute" your question -- I think it enhances it. Questions are *always* improved by not only mentioning that you have researched the issue before asking, but by *showing* what research you've done. ( *this is my opinion, but I don't doubt that I could find support for it somewhere around site policy....try searching MSE for "[what have you tried so far?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=what+have+you+tried+so+far%3F)"* ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just loading the home page and looking does not count as activity. There is no official ruling of what constitutes activity - is it enough to click a link and look at a question or answer? Do you need to vote, or comment, or follow more than one link? (See comments on [How do "consecutive" logins work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204143/147247))

If you're chasing Fanatic, do more than load the home page. Interact with the site - the point of the badge is to form a habit/addiction and merely looking won't do it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not so much chasing it, just over time I noticed the stats creeping up and so have recently *kept my eye on it*. I just use the site naturally, never badge hunting etc. Now knowing more about the *potential* criteria - I think it's possible I may have logged in on SO then a comment notification for another site made me leave SO without doing anything on SO. Accepting your answer based on that. Cheers.